# Android GCM gives Null message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello every one I am using Google cloud messaging in my app. I am following android hive tutorial for my app.link of the tutorial is given below.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

All is working fine for me but the problem is that when a message is sent from remote server, on client side i receive alert of message but having no message just written null message. I am receiving null message. how can i fix it?

### Java Code on Message Receive

/**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */

```
  @Override
  protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

### Server side code

```
//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {

}


/**
 * Sending Push Notification
 */
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    // include config
    include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."*****");

    $apiKey = "*******";
    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
   // if ($result == FALSE) {
   //     die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   // }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

}

### array of mesage

```
   $message = array("message" => $message);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a guess, Make sure the `key` which send from the server is same as you used in the client side. In this tutorial its `price` . So make sure both are same.

**Server side:** `$message = array("price" => $message);`

**Android:**

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }
```

Comment: its not a actual answer

Comment: Why dude? I mentioned it,Its a guess and there is a chance he missed it.

Comment: you should suggest him for showing server side code before guessing

Comment: i am using my key message on both side

Comment: @Amy ohh k. any way I post it. Next time for sure I will consider it.

Comment: @Amy my server side code is same as given in tutorial

Comment: @Mansoor Khan -Can you plz post your server side code.

Comment: @MansoorKhan what you are actually passing in message ?

Comment: @RemeesMSyde yes your guess was right same thin was explaining Eran so you first explained that's why i Accepted it

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a "message" parameter from the server :

```
$message = array("message" => $message);
```

You should change the client code from :

```
String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
```

to :

```
String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
```

This way the client code would read the parameter you sent to it from the server.

Comment: the from server passing the whole array with product with "price" key