# Android: GCM Push notification Implementation, in onMessageReceived method soemtimes "from" is null

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM in my android application by using the google provided tutorial. Everything works fine but sometimes the "from" parameter of onMessageReceived method is null. Following is my GcmListenerService

```
enter code herepublic class MsgLstnrSvc extends GcmListenerService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    String message = data.getString("message");
    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }
}

    private String LOG_AREA = "MsgLstnrSvc";
}
```

May I know what could be the reason for this? I never did GCM integration before this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Double check if you are using the `key` that is sent from the server and in the app are the same.

for example:

Server

```
{
"to": "/topics/foo-bar",
"data": {
"message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
}
}
```

Client

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
String message = data.getString("message");
Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
// message received from some topic.
} else {
// normal downstream message.
}

// ...
}
```

for more information look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520054/android-gcm-gives-null-message?rq=1) on how to implement the GCM message for server and client app.